# Numbering figure windows using the subplots command in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot, figure

Is there a way to number the figure when using the subplots in command in matplotlib.pyplot?
When I want to have a single plot in the figure, I can use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(2)
plot(x,y)
```

And this creates Figure 2 and plots the plot in it. However, I can't do the same when using subplots

```
plt.figure(3)
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax[0].plot(x,y)
```

This basically displays a new figure 3 and then another figure 4 which has the subplots in it. I want to number the one that has the subplots.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The figure that gets created with subplots get automatically numbered. You can check this by doing:

```
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
print(fig1.number)
# 1

fig2, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
print(fig2.number)
# 2
plt.figure(2)  # this will not create a new figure
```

Using the object-oriented approach, I can't see a reason why you would want to set the figure number.

However, if you really wanted to do this, looking at the documentation of [`pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html), there are **`fig_kw`** that get passed to [`pyplot.figure`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure). Here, the first argument in the documentation is `num=` where you can specify the figure number. You can therefore use this argument in `plt.subplots()`:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, num=99)
print(fig.number)
# 99
```

Comment: Thanks DavidG,

It worked, I didn't catch the keyword argument 'num' in the documentation. Thanks for pointing it out.

However, it didn't serve the purpose as to what I wanted to do. I wanted to run a code that generates multiple figures, where each figure plots something unique and I wanted to visualize the changes in each plot due to a change in one of the parameters (2 plots, one after the parameter change and before the parameter change overlaid on top of each other instead of generating new figures with the new data).

For that purpose, Jay Patel's approach (below) worked.

Comment: Thanks, this way I could finally change the saved filename in jupyter notebook / lab (using matplotlib widget -> save icon after plotting graph).

Answer (score 0):

After having called `plt.show()` you can't plot to those figures again (unless and untill you are in some interactive session(?)). So let's assume you haven't called plt.show(). In that case you can reactivate the first figure by figure(1).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,4))
fig.suptitle('First figure instance')
```

[image: OutputImage]

Now Let's create second plot using below code,

```py
plt.figure(2, figsize=(10,5))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(np.random.rand(3,2))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(np.random.rand(3,2))
plt.suptitle('second plot')

sub1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
plt.plot(np.random.rand(3,2))
sub2 = fig.add_subplot(224)
plt.plot(np.random.rand(3,2))
plt.show()
```

[image: OutputImage2]